# Smartgit and Windows 8.1 - Context menu integration not working

Tags: windows-8.1, context-menu, file-association, right-click

`The file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. ...`

The usual error message. I have installed `shmnview` (by Nirsoft), and checked the context menu entry.
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\bin\smartgit.exe" "-open" "%1"`

If I copy out the command into `Win+R`, it works perfect. It opens the directory I give.

Regkey looks like this:
- Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\smartgit\command
- Smartgit folder have a `(default)` value, saying "Open in Smartgit"
- `command` folder under it have another `(default)` value with the command I pasted above.

**So how comes it fails with Explorer right-click?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if you already got a solution, but I had the same problem and solved it with the following registry-entries:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\smartgit]
@="Open in SmartGit"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\smartgit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SmartGit\\bin\\smartgit.exe\" --open \"%V\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\smartgit]
@="Open in SmartGit"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\smartgit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SmartGit\\bin\\smartgit.exe\" --open \"%V\""
```

Just copy and paste it into a textfile, name it the way you want but with the  filename extension ".reg" and run it. Restart explorer.exe and it should work.

Comment: Further explanation of your registry change would improve the answer

Answer (score 0):

My registry already had the entries above - my problem was UX. You need to select a folder in Explorer to open in SmartGit - right-clicking in the empty space in the right-side pane and clicking "Open in Smartgit" throws the error.